# How do I get a js file to run in Next.js backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, bullmq

I have a few lines of code in a file that I use to instantiate a worker for bullmq. It works independently from the rest of the server so Next.js never runs it since it's not imported anywhere.

e.g. I have the following in a standalone file that I want the server to run.

```
const emailWorker = new Worker("emailSchedule", emailWorkerJob, {
  connection: redisConfiguration
});
```

I ended up exporting `emailWorker` and importing it into some file that gets called by an API to force the code run. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by setting `autorun: false` in the worker, then exporting to one of the file that gets loaded and calling `emailWorker.run()`

`emailWorker.js`

```
const emailWorker = new Worker("emailSchedule", emailWorkerJob, {
  connection: <<redis connection>>,
  autorun: false
});

export default emailWorker;
```

`bullmq.js`

```
import emailWorker from "./workers/emailWorker"
...
emailWorker.run()
```